# How to find inverse of a matrix with one constant variable (using arrays)?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, sympy

I am trying to find the inverse of this but numpy seems to only find inverses for numbers. I have `alpha` being not equal to zero.

How do I do this?

```
from sympy import *
import numpy as np 
import scipy.linalg 

A = np.array([[1,2,3],[2,2,3],[3,4,5]])
B = np.array([[1,0,3],[8,2,3],[3,9,5]])

alpha = symbols('a')
K = A - alpha*B
print(np.linalg.inv(K))
```

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, the NumPy `inv` function expects numeric input. The SymPy documentation about the [basic methods](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/matrices.html#basic-methods) for the SymPy Matrix object says "To find the inverse of a matrix, just raise it to the -1 power."

So...

```
from sympy import *
import numpy as np 
import scipy.linalg 

A = np.array([[1,2,3],[2,2,3],[3,4,5]])
B = np.array([[1,0,3],[8,2,3],[3,9,5]])

alpha = symbols('a')
K = A - alpha*B

M = Matrix(K)
print("M:")
print(repr(M))
print()
print("inv(M):")
print(repr(M**-1))
```

Output:

```
M:
Matrix([
[  1 - a,       2, 3 - 3*a],
[2 - 8*a, 2 - 2*a, 3 - 3*a],
[3 - 3*a, 4 - 9*a, 5 - 5*a]])

inv(M):
Matrix([
[                      (17*a - 2)/(181*a**2 - 33*a + 2), -(27*a - 2)/(181*a**2 - 33*a + 2),                             6*a/(181*a**2 - 33*a + 2)],
[                      (31*a - 1)/(181*a**2 - 33*a + 2),   (4*a - 4)/(181*a**2 - 33*a + 2),                     -(21*a - 3)/(181*a**2 - 33*a + 2)],
[-(66*a**2 - 38*a + 2)/(181*a**3 - 214*a**2 + 35*a - 2),   (9*a + 2)/(181*a**2 - 33*a + 2), -(2*a**2 + 12*a - 2)/(181*a**3 - 214*a**2 + 35*a - 2)]])
```

As noted by @OscarBenjamin in a comment, you can also use the `inv` method, i.e. `M.inv()`.

Comment: A sympy matrix also has an `inv` method i.e. `M.inv()` for the inverse.